# Error with rake rdoc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rakefile

I have been working on a rails 4 app. Everything was working- it was deployed -I was styling it but heroku wasn't compiling the assets so I started rake assets:precompile.
The style changes were pushed and the live site was fine.
At some point rake got messed up. Because now when I try to run a rails command or even start the rails server I get this errror in terminal:

```
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
```

It references line 3 in my rakefile:

```
require 'rake/rdoctask'
```

After changing this line to

```
require 'rdoc/task'
```

and then trying to start the server, I get this:

```
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/gempackagetask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rubygems/packagetask' instead.
```

It references rakefile line 4 which I then changed, tried to start the server and get:

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- rubygems/packagetask
```

This is a problem with rails - any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

try running this command in your console

```
locate rubygems | grep "package"
```

maybe you find a line like this one

> /home/yourname/.rbenv/versions/yourversion/lib/ruby/yourversion/rubygems/package_task.rb

rename "rubygems/packagetask" with "rubygems/package_task" and you will not get the error again.